# How do I deal with unknown installation error code -505?

Tags: google-play-store, 5.0-lollipop

I have a Nexus 7 and it has just been updated to Android 5.

Two apps give me trouble after the system upgrade, games that my kids play. Dumb Ways to Die and VVVVVV. Both of these had icons after the upgrade but when clicked a popup appeared saying "App not installed". I attempt to install them. The download is fine. The install begins. And then an error message:

> Unknown error code during application installation: "-505"

The exact same error for both apps. I've restarted the device to no avail.

I have no idea what to do next. Please could some kind soul give me advice on how I might remedy this problem.

Answer (score 10):

## TL;DR

This issue occurs when an app is trying to re-declare an existing permission, with error message `INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION`. It mainly affected apps that are based on Adobe AIR (package prefix with `com.air`). The **main cause** is the different code implementation in Lollipop 5.0 when verifying a certificate's signature used to sign an app. For the solution, just skip over to the "Solution" part.

**Update**: Google has fixed this issue on Lollipop 5.0.1.

---

### Technical Details

Excerpts from [Android L Developer Preview issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1668&thanks=1668&ts=1413847566) which are linked from [an entry on AOSP issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77808),

[Post #4](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1668#c4):

> logcat tells me there's a conflict with redeclaring permissions during installation (in my case, Amazon is trying to redeclare getui.permission.GetuiService, which is already owned by Camera 360)

[Post #12's LogCat](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1668#c12):

```
10-25 08:06:37.805   749   824 W PackageManager: Package com.tencent.mm attempting to redeclare permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND already owned by com.google.android.gsf
10-25 08:06:37.926  4812  4812 D Finsky  : [1] PackageInstallerImpl.cancelSession: Canceling session 121130466 for com.tencent.mm
10-25 08:06:37.926  4812  4812 E Finsky  : [1] PackageInstallerImpl.handleCommitCallback: Error -505 while installing com.tencent.mm: INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION: Package com.tencent.mm attempting to redeclare permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND already owned by com.google.android.gsf
10-25 08:06:37.926  4812  4812 W Finsky  : [1] 4.installFailed: Install failure of com.tencent.mm: -505 null
10-25 08:06:37.933   749   749 D ZenLog  : intercepted: 0|com.android.vending|-973170826|null|10017,!priority
10-25 08:06:37.933   749   749 V NotificationService: pkg=com.android.vending canInterrupt=false intercept=true
10-25 08:06:37.964  4812  4812 D Finsky  : [1] InstallerTask.cancelCleanup: Cancel running installation of com.tencent.mm
```

Excerpts from [AOSP issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79089),

[Post #4](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79089#c4)

> In API19 the new X509CertImpl(encCert) wraps the certificate (which is already parsed and ready for SHA1 computation), while in API 21, the certificate is forwarded as byte stream, parsed again and processed by a certificate factory. Which factory that is, depends on the context. In case of the L devices I tested on, the factory will create an OpenSSLX509Certificate. Unfortunately, there is something in our certificate which openssl has trouble with and the fingerprint changes during openssl processing. I can reproduce this also with the openssl tool, when I convert our certificate into some other format (e.g., PEM).
>
> If the SHA1 would be computed directly on 'encCert.getEncoded()' it would be correct in both cases.

---

### Solution

**Update**: As of 2014-12-04, Google has fixed this issue on Lollipop 5.0.1. For those who didn't do any workaround trying to reinstall the app, you can flash Lollipop 5.0.1 image when it's ready/wait for the OTA.

[Post #20, #21](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79089#c20)

> Looks like this has been fixed in 5.0.1:
>
> https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/6632d8c9d8d1a3ac338d541676148677641bafe3
>
> https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/32a22c44b8351c1cccd3a1f9c47a33469d9378e0
>
> > Status: Released

[Committer's note](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/32a22c44b8351c1cccd3a1f9c47a33469d9378e0)

> Recover apps with malformed certificates.
>
> There was a window of time in Lollipop where we persisted certificates
>   after they had passed through a decode/encode cycle.  The well-written
>   OpenSSL library was liberal when decoding (allowing slightly malformed
>   certs to be parsed), but then strict when encoding, giving us
>   different bytes for effectively the same certificate.
>
> A related libcore change (0c990ab4a90b8a5492a67b2b728ac9a4a1ccfa1b)
>   now returns the original bytes verbatim, fixing both pre-Lollipop
>   installs and installs after that change.
>
> This change recovers any apps that had been installed during the
>   window of time described above by doing a one-time check to see if
>   the certs are effectively equal.

---

<sup>Please refer to [older revision](https://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/88247/2) for other suggested solutions.</sup>

Comment: I have the same as David: nothing to uninstall from the device, ADB does not see my device, attempts to install again result in -505 from Google Play and undescriptive error when installed from local APK. Switching to Guest is not helpful either.

Comment: Well, I just realized I faced this problem too. I've successfully uninstalled the problematic apps with `adb`, but I couldn't reinstall it. Note that the app I want to install has `air.com` prefix as the package name. It seems this is more of an issue between Google, Adobe Air, and the app developers. Until at least one of them fix it, the app won't be possible to be installed. I starred the issue to get update from Google.

Comment: Edit your answer with your comment. That info is helpful. +1

Comment: I'm having the same error on 5.1.1 (cyanogenmod 12.1 galaxy s3 latest nightly). Did they somehow have old code, or is this a more recent bug?

Comment: I'm having this issue on Android 6.0 Marshmallow. Was there aver a solution to this, or just wait for an OTA?

Comment: @Ben, this post mentions the issues with INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION, which was fixed with 5.0.1. I got this error with Marshmellow, due to INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER. I use the Facebook SDK Share dialog's provider, which was declared in both my debug and release builds, preventing installation of the release build from the Google Play Store. You can see the exact message browsing through your adb logcat. In my case, I chose to rename my debug build's <provider> through the use of manifestPlaceholders in my provider name.