# Error code 505 during app installation.

Tags: google-play-store

Error code 505 during app installation problem has resurfaced with Lollipop 5.02 upgrade. Solution suggestions welcomed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I deal with unknown installation error code -505?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88214/how-do-i-deal-with-unknown-installation-error-code-505)

Comment: That one dealt with 5.01 version of Lollipop not Sony Xperia Z3 5.02 update.

Comment: Just read the previous answer - it's a generic problem.

Comment: Sorry, but generic problem doesn't compute. Already read whole referenced answer which states that Google resolved problem for 5.01 yet seems as they let it loose again on 5.02 Lollipop update. Most frustrating.

Comment: The error is still defined by the code. It doesn't redefine as something else each time. So, it is clear they re-introduced the error a different way by trying to fix something this new release.

Comment: Ok. So in other words, for the time being, no solution yet must live wit

Comment: P.s. Sorry, so called smartphone has low I.Q.; no solution yet, must live with unresolving problem for the time being.

Comment: I don't think this question should closed as a dupe given that it was fixed between versions. Clarifying why another near-duplicate does not fit is exactly what we want, so thank you for that.

Comment: On the other hand, the code is **505**, not -505, unless there's a typo, which make this a different issue than the one mentioned.