# Unistalled Updates on pre-installed app

Tags: google-play-store, facebook, crashes

So my Facebook wasn't working, and would only load for a while then crash when I tried to open it. I uninstalled the app updates, then tried to install them again but when the updates were installing, a screen text would appear saying "Error Code 505." The app was already on the phone, and I don't think I can uninstall in the app without rooting the phone, which is something I rather not do. Anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Pointer for the error 505: [How do I deal with unknown installation error code - 505 ?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/88214/16575) (hint: our [google-play-store tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info) has a list of playstore errors)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing FAcebook APK manually following this steps :

1. on your phone go to `settings > security` and check the unknown source check box
2. Download the latest (to the date of this answer) facebook apk from [here](http://mars.androidapksfree.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/com.facebook.katana-v39.0.0.0.88-12733034-Android-5.0.apk)
3. after the download is finish click on the apk in the list of Downloaded items or go to /sdcard/downloads with a file manager app like [es file explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) and open the apk file.
4. the installation screen should appear showing the permissions asked by the app click on `install` at the botton of the screen.
5. wait for the installation to finish then click on open to open facebook app. (now you have the latest facebook app let's fix the playstore issue)
6. Now go to Settings > Applications > all ,search the play store app and click on it.
7. The info about the play store appear ,wait until the delete data button is click-able then click on it and confirm.
8. Now go back to your hame screen and launch the play store and wait for it to load you account then go to `my applications` tab you should see the facebook app there (if it's not try rebooting your phone).
9. You are all set facebook is to latest version and will be updated normally from play store.