# McAfee Free Antivirus won't update from Play Store returning error -505

Tags: applications, google-play-store, updates, 5.1-lollipop

I am putting McAfee in System/app directory to prevent standard users from uninstalling it.

Once I try to update the package from Play Store, the download progress reaches 100% and when it tries to replace the old package I am getting **Error -505**

After a searching, it looks like Android Lollipop have an issue with Adobe Air application, but FYI this is **Lollipop 5.1**

This is what i am getting from bug repport: **different signatures** ?? any ideas??

```
Session 1987113136:
  userId=0 installerPackageName=com.android.vending installerUid=10018 createdMillis=1437157124890 
  stageDir=/data/app/vmdl1987113136.tmp stageCid=null 
  mode=1 installFlags=0x12 installLocation=1 sizeBytes=10749412 appPackageName=com.wsandroid.suite appIcon=false 
  appLabel=Security & Antivirus -FREE originatingUri=null referrerUri=null abiOverride=null 
  mClientProgress=1.0 mProgress=0.90000004 mSealed=true mPermissionsAccepted=true mDestroyed=true mBridges=1 
  mFinalStatus=-7 
  mFinalMessage=Package com.wsandroid.suite signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!`
```

Comment: Please see: [How do I deal with unknown installation error code -505?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/88214/16575) (which is probably what you're referring to). A signature mismatch suggests you're installed the original app from a different source (is that so?), and/or the file has been tampered with (someone modified the `.apk` to e.g. introduce additional "features" such as malware).

Comment: Actually the APK isn't altered this is  why i'm asking

Comment: Still missing details on the other open question (installation source). To give you an example: F-Droid always compiles apps directly from the sources, and thus has to use its own certificate for the signing process. So this error would pop up if you try to update an app you've installed from F-Droid using a different source such as Google Play.

Comment: What's strange now is  when putting the  apk in  userdata it will update normally, is it firmware signature issue?

Comment: Abdel, unless you specify the required details we won't be able to help you. Did you install from a different source than used for the update now? Where in "userdata" did you put the file (exact path, please)? Did you remove the `.apk` from `/system/app` before? My crystal ball is just out to be serviced, so I cannot see that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The app with this package name: com.wsandroid.suite was not signed by the same certificate as the one from the Play store.  This is a fundamental security requirement.  You will have to make sure the app you are installing originally is signed with the same key as the one in the Play store.

There is no way to get around this security requirement (matching signatures) to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Actually, there is a way around this (requiring root, the Xposed framework, and the XInstaller module) – but that should only be used in rare exceptions. There's a good reason for this security measure.