# Cannot install Google Camera on Nexus 5 running CM 12, neither from Play Store, nor with ADB

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-play-store, adb, installation, apk

I need to reinstall Google Camera, and I tried to remove it via Settings -> Applications. Everything went fine, but when I tried to install it back via Play Store, it said:

> Unknown error code during application install: -505.

I've then attempted to install it's APK via ADB. It showed the error  `INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS`. But I'm pretty sure it's removed, I've checked `/system/app`, `/data/app`, and `/data/data` for any residual files, but there's none.

Installing APK with -r key yields `INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE`.

Package manager  `pm list packages` doesn't list Google Camera, which is only logical, since it's removed. But then how could it "already exist"? I wonder what to do and how to bring Google Camera back.

Comment: Ah, yes. Uninstalling via pm also fails with internal error, probably because there's no such package.

Comment: Was Google camera a system app? Did you install it at first along gaps in a fresh cyanogenmod install or before from Google play?

Comment: No, it was installed via Google Play after CM installation.

Comment: Have you seen [How do I deal with unknown installation error code -505?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/88214/16575) (hint: our [google-play-store tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info) has a list of errors with links to the corresponding questions ;) Running CM you've got root, try a `pm uninstall <package_name>` to get rid of potential remains – and also check your SD card (yes, the internal, I know it's a Nex) for such.

Comment: Yeah, I've already tried to remove it via pm, but it fails with an internal error (as far as I understand, that means such package is not installed, which is confirmed by `pm list packages` that doesn't list Google Camera).

Comment: Actually, I've just rolled back to last backup and there's both good and bad news. Good - camera app has returned. Bad - I've checked Play Market and Google Camera appears to be not installed. But it's actually there. Trying to install it results in same Error -505. I won't try to remove it any more, but I wonder what could cause such behavior and whether it could be fixed completely.