# Error 505 when installing Facebook Messenger

Tags: 7.0-nougat, facebook-messenger, sony-xperia-z5

I have a Sony Z5 Compact running Nougat.

I am unable to install Facebook Messenger. When I try I get the Error Code -505.

I have tried installing using ADB with the following command:

```
adb install com.facebook.orca_108.0.0.10.70-51197341_minAPI21\(armeabi-v7a\)\(280,360,400,420,480,560,640dpi\)_apkmirror.com.apk
```

Which seems to be the latest stable version from apkmirror.com.

I get the error message:

> Failed to install com.facebook.orca_108.0.0.10.70-51197341_minAPI21(armeabi-v7a)(280,360,400,420,480,560,640dpi)_apkmirror.com.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION: Package com.facebook.orca attempting to redeclare permission com.facebook.receiver.permission.ACCESS already owned by com.facebook.appmanager]

Is this something I have done? The phone is *not* rooted, nor have I unlocked the boot loader.

Apart from wiping the phone is there anything I can do to get the app installed? (I'm aware of all the 3rd clients, but I would really like to solve this problem.)

The app was installed before the upgrade to Android 7, but an update would not install.

I have done the usual steps like restarting, empty cache and data of Play Services, etc.

This is not a duplicate of [How do I deal with unknown installation error code -505?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/88214), which was supposed to be solved with an upgrade to Android 5.0.2. I am running Android 7.

Comment: Good point, @wbogacz – and the answer is right on top of your list: [How do I deal with unknown installation error code -505?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/88214/16575)

Comment: @Izzy just checked the link you provided. This has no relevance to my problem. They are talking about it being fixed in 5.0.1. I am using 7.0. There is an explanation of the problem, and it's causes but no solution.

Comment: Well, it's the very same underlying cause – as you can clearly see by your error message: `Package com.facebook.orca attempting to redeclare permission com.facebook.receiver.permission.ACCESS already owned by com.facebook.appmanager`. So your solution would be a) to uninstall `com.facebook.appmanager` or b) have its developer fix the package (or c) not install `com.facebook.katana`). Not sure where that one originates, it's not listed on Playstore. The two packages cannot coexist if they both declare the same permission as their own.

Comment: From what I gathered from a quick Google search, it's a builtin service mainly used to support Gear VR.

Comment: I cannot uninstall 'com.facebook.appmanager' or 'com.facebook.system'. I have disabled them but that does not help.

Comment: I have also removed my Google account from the phone, and restarted, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: @William that's what I was pointing at. It's nothing the user can solve, the devs must fix it. If an app asks twice to *use* the same permission, the second request can be safely ignored ("you're already allowed"). But if it *declares to own* a permission already owned by another, that cannot be ignored; it'd be like [Salomon ordering the child spliced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon#Wisdom) :) So, in short: unless your device is rooted and you can remove `com.facebook.manager`, there's nothing you can do. Not sure if `adb shell "pm hide com.facebook.manager"` would achieve a thing.

Comment: @Izzy I don't see other people having this same problem. This is a very common phone, trying to install one of the most common apps. Am I the only having this problem?

Comment: The fact that facebook can not be installed because it is already in the system means the app came built in and you probably did `adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.facebook` assuming that you did not have root privillege. If you actually did disable(which you meant uninstall), you can do pm enable from adb shell.

Answer (score 1):

My girlfriend and I both Sony Xperia Z5 Compact have the same problem (Error 505) after we had updated to Android 7 Nougat. I think for most people, the problem will become public when the old Facebook app gets outdated and force an update. I was too naive to uninstall Facebook, Messenger, and Site Manager for a fresh install try, and now am only able to use these Facebook platforms on a browser. I posted the same problem in Sony Support Forum and am also surprised that such popular app errors on Android 7 result only in 1-3 problem topics at this time.

The official answer from Sony: Make a factory reset because the problem happens with an update. Not the expected answer - but seems the only solution, when the company doesn't want to fix these issues.

Comment: This is such a hassle when you start to use 2FA apps like authenticator. Is there a way to make a 'mirror' of the phone so I can wipe it clean and then get everything back the way it was quickly without having to re-login on all my apps?